# Upload function working in safari but not in mobile wkWebView ios app

Tags: ios, swift, mobile

I have got a file upload system attached my my website that works perfect on the mobile safari. I can access the iCloud, Photo Libraray, and Camera.

However after I implemented it into the wkWebView in our mobile app the upload system no longer works.

When I load the wkWebView and click on the button it brings up the options of where I want to grab the file from. I select Photo Library and it closes the webview and takes me back to my first viewController.

Here is the webview code:

```
  //Camera
         AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(forMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) { response in
        if response {

            //access granted
        } else {

        }
    }

    //Photos
    let photos = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()
    if photos == .notDetermined {
        PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({status in
            if status == .authorized{
                //...
            } else {}
        })
    }

    let requestObj = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://example.com/chat.php?use=\(userId)")!)
            corepage.load(requestObj);
  }
```

I also have added the information to the info.plist as well. However, this didn't solve my issue of the page reverting back to the main viewController when clicking any of the options of uploading a file.

Thanks Guys!

Comment: maybe you are basically accidentally closing the WebView / controller somewhere?  what happens if you "cancel" the upload, does it go back ok?

Comment: @Fattie when I click cancel it does the exact same thing...which is very wierd because on mobile safari it doesn't do that...when I cancel it it stays there and does nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have gotten it figured out:

In the viewcontroller that has my webview I added:

```
override func dismiss(animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)?) {
    if (self.presentedViewController != nil) {
        super.dismiss(animated: flag, completion: completion)
    }
}
```

This prevented the dimissal issue.

Comment: That's not really solving the issue.  That's just putting a band-aid over it.  You should find out what is calling the ViewController to be dismissed.  If you put a breakpoint in the code you added, what is triggering the dismissal?